# How to deserialize and cast to Long all numbers?

Tags: json, serialization, jackson

The Jackson deserialize and cast to Integer all numbers if value in range of Integers instead it cast to Long. I would like to cast ALL values to Long.
Is it exist easy solution of issue?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing Jackson to deserialize to specific primitive type](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316689/forcing-jackson-to-deserialize-to-specific-primitive-type)

Answer (score 6):

Jackson deserializes to type you tell it to, so if you declare property to be of type long or Long it would construct it as long. But maybe you are binding to "untyped" structure like `Map`? If all values are of type `Long`, you could just declare type appropriately, like:

```
Map<String,Long> map = objectMapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<Map<String,Long>>() { });
```

Alternatively might be able to add custom Deserializer for `Object.class` with different handling (default deserializer is `org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.UntypedObjectDeserializer`).

It might help if I knew what you are actually trying to do -- `Integer` and `Long` are both numbers, so often distinction does not matter a lot... so what is the reason to require Longs?

Comment: The deserialized numbers are IDs of objects that I would like to retrieved through the Hibernate. When I use Integer it throw an exception that it can convert from integer to long.

Comment: Then the easiest way might be to explicitly just convert these, something like 'Long id = numberValue.longValue();'.
Unless if map only has numeric values, in which you can declare types as Map<String,Long> (as I mentioned above)

Comment: @StaxMan explicit conversion will become redundant when the IDs become long so wouldn't some form of type casting (e.g. JsonTypeInfo) be preferable?

Comment: Jackson does type co(nv)ercions where necessary. So if POJO indicated that `long` or `Long` are needed, that's what you'd get. The original post is vague enough that I don't really know enough to know what the right answer is. But polymorphic type inclusion does not seem to be part of the picture.