# Forcing Jackson to deserialize to specific primitive type

Tags: java, json, jackson

I am serializing and deserializing following domain object to JSON using Jackson 1.8.3

```
public class Node {
    private String key;
    private Object value;
    private List<Node> children = new ArrayList<Node>();
    /* getters and setters omitted for brevity */
}
```

Object is then serialized and deserialized using following code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.writeValue(destination, rootNode);
```

And then later deserialized with

```
mapper.readValue(destination, Node.class);
```

The original values of the object are either Strings, Doubles, Longs or Booleans. However, during serialization and deserialization Jackson transforms Long values (such as 4) to Integers.

How can I "force" Jackson to deserialize numeric non-decimal values to Long instead of Integer?

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140760/how-to-deserialize-and-cast-to-long-all-numbers

Comment: Beware that you may not deserialize a large long-value in Javascript exactly, because Javascript numbers are always 64bit floating points with (only) 52bit mantissa.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If type is declared as java.lang.Object, Jackson uses 'natural' mapping which uses Integer if value fits in 32 bits. Aside from custom handlers you would have to force inclusion of type information (either by adding @JsonTypeInfo next to field / getter; or by enabling so-called "default typing").

Comment: This is not very satisfying behavior. It means that any time you deserialize an untyped number you will always have to cast it and call longValue() or intValue(). It would be great if Jackson had a way to force all numbers to Long; at least behavior would be predictable.

Comment: @stickfigure That wouldn't be much better -- keeping in mind that JSON allows values larger than what 64-bit holds, so you could still get `BigInteger` (incidentally, there is `DeserializationFeature.USE_BIG_INTEGER_FOR_INTS` to force all integral numbers to be converted to `BigInteger`). But if you want any specific coercion rules, you probably want to write custom deserializer for `java.lang.Object` and get rules 100% the way you want them -- everyone has their own preferences.

Comment: While that may be theoretically true, it is uncommon in practice. Most Java applications don't use BigInteger, and most Java applications do use Long for numeric ids. Which means anytime you go through an untyped situation (say a Map) you need to write code like `((Number)map.get("key")).longValue()`. If you are concerned about null-checks the code is even more tedious. I opened a feature request in the jackson databinding git repo.

Comment: btw. I think this solution only works if you are able to re-serialize all your data that is experiencing the issue.

Answer (score 45):

There is a new feature in Jackson 2.6 specifically for this case:

configure the ObjectMapper to use `DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS`

see https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/504

> cowtowncoder pushed a commit that closed this issue on May 19, 2015 
>     Fix #504 and #797

Comment: this was the easiest solution to use as it works to deserialize data that is already in json string format. thank you.

Comment: TL;DR: Having created ObjectMapper like this `ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper(...);` 
one should do: `om.configure(DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS, true);`

Answer (score 4):

I ended up creating a custom deserializer, since in my application logic there are only four different types for values (`Double`, `Long`, `Integer` and `String`).

I'm not sure if this is the best possible solution but it works for now.

```
public class MyDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

@Override
public Object deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt)
        throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    try {
        Long l = Long.valueOf(p.getText());
        return l;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // Not a Long
    }
    try {
      Double d = Double.valueOf(p.getText());
      return d;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
      // Not a Double
    }
    if ("TRUE".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getText())
          || "FALSE".equalsIgnoreCase(p.getText())) {
      // Looks like a boolean
      return Boolean.valueOf(p.getText());
    }
    return String.valueOf(p.getText());
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used something like the below to work around this problem.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Message {
    public Long ID;

    @JsonCreator
    private Message(Map<String,Object> properties) {
        try {
            this.ID = (Long) properties.get("id");
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            this.ID = ((Integer) properties.get("id")).longValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This shall throw ClassCastExcpetion (where you are trying to convert it to long; unless your value is really more then max value of Integer.

Comment: @TyagiAkhilesh are you sure? Doesn't seem likely to me.

Comment: Give it a try... That happens for me at least. When I have a json string in test case and try to create object, it does give that exception.

Comment: Hold on. Your above code does work fine though, as you are catching ... Sorry .. I was emphasising that casting is not really best way. Use covertValue better.

Comment: Better is subjective.

Answer (score 2):

In my case I did not want to use DeserializationFeature.USE_LONG_FOR_INTS for ObjectMapper, because it would affect all the project. I used the next solution: use a custom deserializer:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.ObjectCodec;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;

import java.io.IOException;

public class LongInsteadOfIntegerDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public Object deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException {
        ObjectCodec codec = jsonParser.getCodec();
        JsonNode jsonNode = codec.readTree(jsonParser);
        if (jsonNode.isInt()) {
            return jsonNode.asLong();
        }
        return codec.treeToValue(jsonNode, Object.class);
    }
}
```

And add it to the field of type Object:
    public class SomeTOWithObjectField {

```
    //...  other fields

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LongInsteadOfIntegerDeserializer.class)
    private Object value;

    //...  other fields
}
```

And it deserialized integers as longs, but other types like String, boolean, double etc. were deserialized as they should be by default.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wrap a primitive into specific class, you can do follow (example in Kotlin):

```
data class Age(
    @JsonValue
    val value: Int
)
```

And now, your `Int` primitives will be parsed into Age class and vice versa - Age class into Int primitive.

Answer (score 0):

In jackson 2 we can use [TypeReference](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/type/TypeReference.html) to specify the generic type in detail. There is and overloaded method for `readValue()` which takes the *TypeReference* as the 2nd parameter:

> readValue([File|String|etc], com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference))

If you want to get a list of `Long` instead of `Integer`, you can do the following.

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<List<Integer>>() { };
List<Integer> list = mapper.readValue(<jsonString>, ref);
```

This works for maps as well:

```
TypeReference ref = new TypeReference<Map<String,Long>>() { };
Map<String, Long> map = mapper.readValue(<jsonString>, ref);
```

In your case, you can convert your class to a generic one. i.e `Node<T>`. When creating nodes, do as `Node<String/Integer/etc>` And use the type reference to read the value.