# Jackson value conversion with lazy serialization

Tags: java, jackson

I want to convert one Java type to another using [`ObjectMapper.convertValue()`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#convertValue(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Class)). The source object is of a specific type, but the destination type varies. For performance reasons, I want to avoid serializing any source fields that are not defined on the destination type. I know deserialization can be configured to ignore extra fields, but as far as I understand, all the source fields would still be evaluated in the intermediate serialization. Is there a way to create a serializer that would only evaluate fields existing on the destination type?

To put it more generally, when converting between Java types, can the schema of the destination type be used to determine the serialization strategy for the source type?

Comment: Taking a look http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonHowToCustomSerializers you can see that you can add your custom serializer.

Comment: @user1929959 I know you can do custom serialization. What I'm trying to figure out is how to adapt it to the destination type in a value conversion.

Comment: Maybe you could look at using http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews, you would have to change your convertValue into a two step serialize then deserialize.

Comment: @shmosel Just I found another related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316689/forcing-jackson-to-deserialize-to-specific-primitive-type. Can be useful?

Comment: @roby That would require me to know in advance which fields are to be serialized. In my case, it would depend on the destination type for a particular conversion.

Comment: @user1929959 Not really.

Comment: If you are concerned about performance, you should not use this approach at all, especially if your objects form a deep graph. It is far from having good performance, as it first serializes the source object to json and then deserializes it to the destination type. Although the two steps of this conversion process are somehow merged into one big optimized step with the help of memory data structures, I've found it to be extremely slow for deep graphs, i.e. order of seconds for a full airplane reservation object. You'll be better with your own mappers that map directly, or use Orika or Dozer.

Answer (score 0):

No. Like you say, you can make deserializer part ignore properties it does not recognize, but there is no functionality for trimming content serialized.

But are you sure this is an actual performance issue? Intermediate form used (`TokenBuffer`) is a simple sequence of leaf-values, and since `String`s already exists, overhead should be quite low. There is no full serialization into JSON involved, regardless.

Comment: It's not the actual serialization I'm concerned about. I'm using custom serialization which has extra overhead for each field lookup. (Even without custom serialization, there might be a source method `getFoo()` which is expensive to invoke.)

Comment: One thing you can try using would be either dynamic JSON Filters, or even JSON Views. Both can be change on per-call basis, and they will be applied for `convertValue()` too, since serialization code path is used even if physical output isn't. This article -- http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2011/09/entry_461.html -- might help if you are not familiar with these features.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a `BeanSerializer` for an `object` like this:

```
ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper ();
SerializerFactory f = m.getSerializerFactory ();
JsonSerializer <?> j = f.createSerializer (m.getSerializerProviderInstance (), object.getClass ())
```

If `j` is not an instance of `BeanSerializer` then it's a custom serializer and there's no way around serializing the whole thing - and then converting it into a `Map`. But if it is then:

```
BeanSerializer b = (BeanSerializer) j;
for (Iterator <PropertyWriter> p = b.properties (); p.hasNext ();) {
  BeanPropertyWriter w = (BeanPropertyWriter) p.next ();
  String k = w.getName ();
  Object v = w.get (object);
}
```

Obviously you can delay calling `get()` on the writer for as long as you want. It's a bit hacky but I haven't found a better solution