# Dataflow mixing Integer & Long types

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

In my Dataflow pipeline, I'm setting the field `impressions_raw` as a `Long` in a `com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow` object:

[image]

Further on in my pipeline, I read the `TableRow` back out. But instead of a `Long`, I get back an `Integer`.

[image]

However, if I explicitly set the value to be a `Long` value greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, for example 3 billion, then I get back a `Long`!

[image]
[image]

Is seems that the Dataflow SDK is doing some sort of type check optimization under the hood.

So, without doing ugly type checking, how should one programatically deal with this? (maybe I missed something obvious)

Comment: Could you post some of the code which does the creation, modification, and reading of these objects?

Comment: Nick, I posted an example with good syntax at: https://gist.github.com/dhalperi/9f13ab33eab59083dc1a#file-example-for-so-java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for the report. Unfortunately, this problem is fundamental with the use of `TableRow`. We strongly recommend solution 1 below: convert away from `TableRow` as soon as practical in your pipeline.

The `TableRow` object in which you are storing these values is serialized and deserialized by Jackson, inside of [`TableRowJsonCoder`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/blob/master/sdk/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/sdk/coders/TableRowJsonCoder.java). Jackson has exactly the behavior you're describing -- that is, for this class:

```java
class MyClass {
    Object v;
}
```

it will serialize an instance with `v = Long.valueOf(<number>)` as `{v: 30}` or `{v: 3000000000}`. On deserializing, however, it will determine the type of the object using the number of bits needed to represent the answer. See [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316689/forcing-jackson-to-deserialize-to-specific-primitive-type).

Two possible solutions come to mind, with solution 1 strongly recommended:

1. Do not use `TableRow` as an intermediate value. In other words, convert to POJO as soon as possible. The key reason this type-mixup happens is that `TableRow` is essentially a `Map<String, Object>` and Jackson (or other coders) cannot know that you want a `Long` back. With a POJO, the types would be clear.

   The other advantage of switching off of `TableRow` is to get to an efficient coder, say, `AvroCoder`. Because `TableRow`s are encoded and decoded to/from JSON, the encoding is both verbose and slow -- shuffling `TableRow` will be both CPU- and I/O-intensive. I expect you'll see much better performance with Avro-coded POJOs than if you're passing `TableRow` objects around.

   For an example, see [`LaneInfo` in `TrafficMaxLaneFlow`](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/dataflow/examples/complete/TrafficMaxLaneFlow.java#L99).
2. Write code that can handle both:

   ```java
   long numberToLong(@Nonnull Number n) {
       return n.longValue();
   }
   long x = numberToLong((Number) row.get("field"));

   Long numberToLong(@Nonnull Number n) {
       if (n instanceof Long) {
           // avoid a copy
           return n;
       }
       return Long.valueOf(n.longValue());
   }
   Long x = numberToLong((Number) row.get("field"));
   ```

   You may need additional checks to the second variant if `n` may be `null`.