# java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

Tags: java, casting, unboxing

I'm supposed to receive long integer in my web service.

```java
long ipInt = (long) obj.get("ipInt");
```

When I test my program and put ipInt value = 2886872928, it give me success.
However, when I test my program and put ipInt value = 167844168, it give me error :

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to java.lang.Long

The error is point to the above code.

FYI, my data is in JSON format :

```
{
    "uuID": "user001",
    "ipInt": 16744168,
    "latiTude": 0,
    "longiTude": 0,
}
```

Is there any suggestion so that I can ensure my code able to receive both ipInteger value?

Comment: What's the type of `obj`? How is it created and populated?

Comment: Instead of casting the `int` value try using `Long.parseLong(int)`

Comment: @SherwinObciana: Given that `obj.get("ipInt")` apparently returns `Integer`, I can't see how that would work.

Comment: Some JSON libs allow you to force integer numbers to be parsed as `long`, which would solve your issue altogether. [Here is a solution for jackson](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31564232/5761558) (if that's what you're using)

Answer (score 57, accepted):

Both `Integer` and `Long` are subclasses of `Number`, so I suspect you can use:

```
long ipInt = ((Number) obj.get("ipInt")).longValue();
```

That should work whether the value returned by `obj.get("ipInt")` is an `Integer` reference or a `Long` reference. It has the downside that it will *also* silently continue if `ipInt` has been specified as a floating point number (e.g. `"ipInt": 1.5`) in the JSON, where you might want to throw an exception instead.

You *could* use `instanceof` instead to check for `Long` and `Integer` specifically, but it would be pretty ugly.

Comment: I happen to find it more resilient, with regards to "ill-formed" `1.5` or `1.`, if we assume the contract is that `ipInt` is supposed to be an integer. It will "succeed silently" instead of "crashing explicitly".

Comment: @Matthieu: Do you mean you *prefer* a scenario where invalid data is silently passed through the system, with data loss? I personally prefer invalid data to be caught as early as possible with a hard error. If some code tries to update my bank balance with a non-number, I'd rather that system crashed than set it to 0 :)

Comment: Dear God, I get you ;) I guess it mostly depends on the scenario: when you deal with money, hard crash is obviously preferred. But I have some processes that should (almost) *never* stop, and hence *have to* continue with last-correct configuration. Of course, in that case, we should catch the exception and at least log it.
Ok, as I'm writing that, I'm getting convinced. Thanks :)

Answer (score 8):

We don't know what `obj.get()` returns so it's hard to say precisely, but when I use such methods that return `Number` subclasses, I find it safer to cast it to `Number` and call the appropriate `xxxValue()`, rather than letting the auto-unboxing throw the `ClassCastException`:

```
long ipInt = ((Number)obj.get("ipInt")).longValue();
```

That way, you're doing explicit unboxing to a `long`, and are able to cope with data that could include a `.`, which would return a `Float` or `Double` instead.

Comment: I mark the date: wrote (almost) the same answer than Jon Skeet with (almost) 1000 times less rep ;)

Answer (score 3):

```java
Long.valueOf(jo.get("ipInt").toString());
```

Is ok.

Answer (score 2):

in kotlin I simply use this:

```
val myInt: Int = 10
val myLong = myInt.toLong()
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention the current approach works when you provide a value outside the range of integer, but fails when you are within the integer range. That is an odd behavior for an API, because it seems you *need* to check the return type yourself. You *can* do that. The usual way is with `instanceof`. Something like,

```
long ipInt;
Object o = obj.get("ipInt");
if (o instanceof Integer) {
    ipInt = ((Integer) o).intValue();
} else if (o instanceof Long) {
    ipInt = ((Long) o).longValue();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JSONObject jo = JSON.parseObject(
        "{    \"uuID\": \"user001\",    \"ipInt\": 16744168,    \"latiTude\": 0,    \"longiTude\": 0}");
    System.out.println(jo);
    long sellerId1 =  Long.valueOf(jo.get("ipInt").toString());
    //Long sellerId1 = (long)jo.get("ipInt");
    System.out.println(sellerId1);
}
```

Comment: Please explain what the code does and why it answers the question.

Comment: Some cases this works. Thanks for this!