# Is there way to deserialise {"number1":5L,"number2":5L} to a class having long fields?

Tags: json, jackson, numbers, long-integer, json-deserialization

When I deserialise `JSON`:

```
{"number1":5L,"number2":5L}
```

to a `class` having `long` fields, I get below error:

> JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('L' ): was expecting comma
>   to separate Object entries

How to fix it?

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7316689/forcing-jackson-to-deserialize-to-specific-primitive-type/31564232  One suggestion is @JsonTypeInfo

Comment: Is below answer helpful for you?

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` payload is not valid. Number can not be represented with letter `L` at the end. See below chart:

[image: A number is very much like a C or Java number, except that the octal and hexadecimal formats are not used.]

Above picture comes from [json.org](https://www.json.org/json-en.html). To handle invalid `JSON` we need to implement custom deserialiser for `Long` class:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonDeserializer;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonDeserialize;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.NumberDeserializers;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringJoiner;

public class JsonPathApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        File jsonFile = new File("./resource/test.json").getAbsoluteFile();

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        Id id = mapper.readValue(jsonFile, Id.class);
        System.out.println(id);
    }
}

class LongJsonDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Long> {


    private final NumberDeserializers.LongDeserializer longDeserializer = new NumberDeserializers.LongDeserializer(Long.TYPE, 0L);

    @Override
    public Long deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctxt) throws IOException {
        Long value = longDeserializer.deserialize(p, ctxt);
        goToNextTokenSilently(p);
        return value;
    }

    private void goToNextTokenSilently(JsonParser p) {
        try {
            p.nextToken();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //log if needed
        }
    }
}

class Id {

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LongJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Long number1;

    @JsonDeserialize(using = LongJsonDeserializer.class)
    private Long number2;

    // getters, setters, toString
}
```